# Compiling the latexdiff when adding a subscript before a pmatrix environment causes compilation error

Tags: latexdiff

Consider the following two simple `.tex` files:

`test_old.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$a \begin{pmatrix}a & b\end{pmatrix}$

\end{document}
```

and `test_new.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$a_2 \begin{pmatrix}a & b\end{pmatrix}$

\end{document}
```

Using `latexdiff` to highlight the differences between these two documents (using latexdiff 1.2.0 on windows 10) generates the following `diff.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{article}
%DIF LATEXDIFF DIFFERENCE FILE
%DIF DEL .\test_old.tex   Tue Mar 21 15:42:30 2017
%DIF ADD .\test_new.tex   Tue Mar 21 15:42:31 2017
\usepackage{amsmath}
%DIF PREAMBLE EXTENSION ADDED BY LATEXDIFF
%DIF UNDERLINE PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\RequirePackage[normalem]{ulem} %DIF PREAMBLE
\RequirePackage{color}\definecolor{RED}{rgb}{1,0,0}\definecolor{BLUE}{rgb}{0,0,1} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFadd}[1]{{\protect\color{blue}\uwave{#1}}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdel}[1]{{\protect\color{red}\sout{#1}}}                      %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF SAFE PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddbegin}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddend}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelbegin}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelend}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF FLOATSAFE PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddFL}[1]{\DIFadd{#1}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelFL}[1]{\DIFdel{#1}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddbeginFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddendFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelbeginFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelendFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF END PREAMBLE EXTENSION ADDED BY LATEXDIFF

\begin{document}

%DIF <  $\mathcal C\begin{pmatrix}a & b\end{pmatrix}$
\DIFdelbegin \DIFdel{$a \begin{pmatrix}a & b\end{pmatrix}$
}\DIFdelend %DIF >  $\mathcal C_2 \begin{pmatrix}a & b\end{pmatrix}$
\DIFaddbegin \DIFadd{$a_2 \begin{pmatrix}a & b\end{pmatrix}$
}\DIFaddend 

\end{document}
```

Compiling this file results in the following errors:

```
...\diff.tex:30: Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of \UL@word. [}]
...\diff.tex:30: Paragraph ended before \UL@word was complete. [}]
...\diff.tex:34: Missing } inserted. [\end{document}]
```

What causes this? And how can I prevent it?

Comment: @campa I agree, but was afraid of removing something useful. And it appears I already did removing `hyperref`. Thanks for pointing out, I'll edit

Comment: @campa adding back `hyperref` seems to only remove the very first error. I also tried to remove some parts of the code that seemed more unlikely to be causing issues. Most of the code is from the preamble added by `latexdiff` now, and I'm not sure what can I remove of that

Comment: There are several different errors. The first one (after the edit) is due to calling `\st` in math mode; then `\DIFdel` is used wrongly e.g. in the last equation, where it encloses `\begin{gathered}`; and at some point `ulem` fails too, though I haven't found out yet exactly where. As for not being sure about what can be removed: if the error still shows up, then the removed line wasn't responsible `:-)`

Comment: Using soul (\st) and \uwave for this type of automatic marking is asking for trouble. Beside this the nesting is wrong for the gathered environment.

Comment: @campa `latexdiff` usually works decently enough (in my experience at least), so I'm wondering why all these errors now. In the case of the `gathered` I guess the nesting error is not fixable simply redefining the macro is it? That would require fixing the `latexdiff` script itself.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer what would you suggest of using instead of `uwave` and `st`?

Comment: As pointed out by others, this question right now cannot be answered. There are some obvious problems with the nesting - if latexdiff created this text directly with default, it would be a bug of latexdiff. However, the markup inserted in the beginning is not the standard latexdiff style, telling me that a modified latexdiff or special options were used. latexdiff uses `\sout` for striking-out.  For the MWE, you should isolate one piece giving an error, not several pieces. Putting several pieces in with errors essentially asks others to debug your file.

Comment: Also, for latexdiff related MWE please post old and new file, not just the listing latexdiff created.

Comment: For trouble with underlining styles, try to use `-t CFONT` option to latexdiff - this is less intuitive highlighting in my opinion, but somewhat more robust.

Comment: Finally, your question title is not really helpful. In the process of generating an MWE showing only one problem, you can probably choose a better question title (I am flagging to close as too broad but do not feel discouraged from resubmitting the same issue (one of the issues) with a more focussed question). If you are lucky, the fix for the first problem will allow you to fix the others, too. If not, you can submit another question later.

Comment: @frederik you are right, I'm sorry. I completely changed the question, and focused it on a single simple problem. Do you think this is more answerable?

Comment: Much better, and in fact I have an answer now but unfortunately the question has been placed on hold and I cannot put it in (and don't have the rep to reopen). Briefly, it was a bug in latexdiff. I fixed this now on the github page of latexdiff. As a workaround you can put the `$..$` expression with embedded array environments into an `\mbox`, .i.e. `\mbox{$...$}`. latexdiff is supposed to do this automatically, but there was a problem with that code. I hope after your edit this question will be reopened so I can put in this answer properly and provide more detail (@StefanPinnow  and others)

Comment: @frederik thanks! the question has been reopened now, if you put it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this fails is because the ulem underlining commands break, if the inline-math expression has an array environment. This can be made to work by encapsulating the math expression using `\mbox{$...$}` (this would have to be done either in both old and new file, or in the resulting diff).  As this is a known weakness of ulem latexdiff contained code to add the \mbox to its output where needed.

However, there was a pattern matching bug in latexdiff preventing this from working properly. At the time of writing this bug is fixed in the development version on github but not yet included in a release (it will be included from 1.2.1 onwards). If you do not want to clone the github version, you can apply these two patches by hand:

```
    $begin2=pos($delblock) - $len2;
    $mathblock="%\n\\mbox{$AUXCMD\n$1\n}$AUXCMD\n";
-   next unless $mathblock =~ m/\{$ARRENV\}/ ;
+   next unless ( $mathblock =~ /ARRAYBLOCK/ or $mathblock =~m/\{$ARRENV\};
    substr($delblock,$begin2,$len2)=$mathblock;
    pos($delblock) = $begin2 + length($mathblock);
```

and

```
@@ -2608,7 +2615,7 @@ sub postprocess {
    $len2=length($&);
    $begin2=pos($addblock) - $len2;
    $mathblock="%\n\\mbox{$AUXCMD\n$1\n}$AUXCMD\n";
-   next unless $mathblock =~ m/\{$ARRENV\}/ ;
+   next unless ( $mathblock =~ /ARRAYBLOCK/ or $mathblock =~ m/\{$ARRENV\}/) ;
    substr($addblock,$begin2,$len2)=$mathblock;
    pos($addblock) = $begin2 + length($mathblock);
   }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Which expression do you mean we should wrap? The one in old version, in the new one, or in the diff?

Comment: I have edited the question to clarify. Actually if it is identical in old and new file, there should be no problem